# TypeError: string indices must be integers, while reading a json file with python3

Tags: python, arrays, json, string, typeerror

I'm trying to read a json file and put its content into a list. When I try to do a for loop to get the contents, I am receiving the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Weirdly, if I try to print the file, no problem at all. Does someone know what am I doing wrong? Is the json file ok?

Here's the json file

```
{
"Username": "Final test",
"Email": "teste@email.com",
"Risks": {
    "Risk1": {
        "Name": "Risco 1",
        "Min": "3000",
        "Likely": "5000"
    },
    "Risk2": {
        "Name": "risco2",
        "Min": "4500",
        "Likely": "6000"
    },
    "Risk3": {
        "Name": "risco3",
        "Min": "1500",
        "Likely": "7000"
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the python code:

```
json_file = open('path to file..')
data = json.load(json_file)

lista_json = [data['Username'], data['Email']]
for item in data['Risks']:
    print("item= ", item)
    print("Name, ", data['Risks'][item]['Name'])
    print("Min, ", data['Risks'][item]['Min'])

    lista_json.append(item['Risks'][item]['Name'])
    lista_json.append(item[‘'Risks'][item]['Min'])
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I think your last two lines should be data[‘Risks’], not item[‘Risks’]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to be using a proper quote. `‘` != `'`. Also, you're accessing `item` in the append, not `data` 
This is what you want:

```
json_file = open('path...')
data = json.load(json_file)

lista_json = [data['Username'], data['Email']]
for item in data['Risks']:
    print("item= ", item)
    print("Name, ", data['Risks'][item]['Name'])
    print("Min, ", data['Risks'][item]['Min'])

    lista_json.append(data['Risks'][item]['Name'])
    lista_json.append(data['Risks'][item]['Min'])
```

Comment: Something went wrong during the copy paste. I fixed the ' ' .

Comment: Indeed I agree with ptrstr. For sake of clarity, I would add that invoking `item['Risks']`, given the sample json, is actually trying to index a string (i.e. `item`) with a not-integer index (i.e. `'Risks'`)

Comment: Thank you ptstr. I really didn't noticed that I was calling 'item' twice.